# PHP Wordpress export XML into custom website

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am building a script to upload my wordpress posts into my new website.

But I have about 800 posts, and doing 800 inserts at once, doesn't seem like a good idea.

At this point I am using:

```
$this->xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

and then foreach the posts, but is there a smart way of doing this, without inserting the 800 posts in one request?

Comment: Why do you think inserting 800 posts in one request is bad? Is your script freezing or something?

Comment: There is a lot of filtering and statements of the data, doing that 800 times must be hard for the memory - I also need to point out, that the script will be used multiple times, not only for me, but multiple users.

Comment: Right now, what you're asking is very theoretical... If you want answers that straight to the point that you're struggling with, it's better to present a [mcve] that demonstrates your exact issue.

Comment: That makes sense. 

I am opening an XML file, that I downloaded from my Wordpress page.

In this file I have 800 items ( Posts ) that I need to insert into my database. 

What would be the best approach to do this - Just insert 800 entries at once, or split it up somehow?

This function will be used by multiple of users, so it's not just one time script.